# Going back to the [n] last edited position

Tags: macvim

I read the following on vim tips

> '`*' ('*' is a mark specifier): move to the position of the given
>   mark) - mark '.' is the last edited position

My question is suppose I have two line

```
Line 1 
Line 2 
Line 3 
Line 4
```

Suppose I edited line1 (insert mode) then escaped into normal mode and went to line 4 (edited line 4). What would be the best approach to go back to line 1 (Which was my inital edit).

I was thinking that since `. would take us to the last edited position maybe 
2``. would take us to the second last edited position. Sorry i added two back ticks since one back tick triggers formatting. Any suggestions on how the experts handle this. I know I could use marks but i dont feel like adding a mark to every line I edit unless i have no other option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is the "changelist": `:help changelist`.

Use `3g;` to jump to the third previous change in the "changelist" and `2g,` to jump back 2 steps in the list.

Comment: No `:changelist` found when I checked. But found `:changes`, `changelist`

Comment: @vusan, oops. I initially wrote `:changes` but thought that `:help changelist` would be more appropriate and… in the end I forgot the colon. Thank you.